# VB:NET using LINQ how can i find the row index for a specified string in some Datatable column

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

to check if a string exists in some column i use something like

```
mydatatable.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("somecolumn") = "somestring")
```

but how can i find the row index of `"somestring"`? considering its allowed to exist only once in `mydatatable` , and what if it existed more than once?

Comment: Could you not use singleordefault to return a data row and then get the index of the row if it exists or not?

Comment: @Ric so i just replace .Any with .SingleOrDefault ?

Comment: @Tim has given a great way of finding what you were after.

Comment: @Ric, the default of an Integer is 0, so you cannot use that to immediately get the index. Of course, this is only relevant if you are interested in the index (if want the datarow, I would use FirstOrDefault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload that passes the index:

```
Dim rows = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(r, i) New With {.Row = r, .Index = i}).
    Where(Function(x) x.Row.Field(Of String)("somecolumn") = "somestring")
If rows.Any() Then
    Dim firstIndex As Int32 = rows.First.Index
End If
```